# how to solve dpkg: warning: 'tar' not found in PATH or not executable

Tags: dpkg

I tried your solution but still the same problem exist.

```
gaja@gaja-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for gaja: 
root@gaja-System-Product-Name:/home/gaja# sudo apt-get install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
apache2 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 230 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: warning: 'tar' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
root@gaja-System-Product-Name:/home/gaja#
```